# Ubuntu/Linux unusable lag due to Graphics Driver/Card or Monitor?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Edit: I believe the problem lies with the Graphics driver, card, or my monitor itself. My problem happens even in an installed version of Linux/Ubuntu, not just the live CD. I've tried getting the nvidia driver and following a plethora of guides on this site, but they all lead in me getting a black screen on bootup and having to Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get a terminal. If anyone has any suggestions or anything, I'd greatly apperciate it.

Upon trying to install ANY form of Linux (tried Ubuntu 13.04, Mint 15 Cinnamon), I have a few problems:

First off, I get EXTREME lag in both of their Live CDs. It starts to completely hang for minutes at a time, and then eventually the screen goes black and never displays anything again.

Here are my specs:

> ASUS P8P67 Pro Rev 3.1 Motherboard (Latest BIOS 8/6/2013)
>   Intel i7 2600K Processor
>   128GB OCZ SOLID3 SSD (Latest FW 8/6/2013)
>   1TB Seagate Barracuda 7200RPM HDD
>   NVIDIA GeForce GTX 580
>   Yamakasi Catleap Q270 (2560x1440 @ 60Hz) via Dual-Link DVI

Any ideas? I can't even use the LiveCD or the OS for longer than about 5-10 seconds until the hangups start. I tried getting the Performance Analyzer open once, and I didn't notice any weird CPU activity, but I wasn't able to check out SSD/HDD activity.

If this question is a duplicate and I missed it, please let me know and I will be happy to remove it.

Any help/answers/suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Please look for suspicious messages in System Log or `dmesg` after such an event occurred. It sounds to me like an issue with the mainboard. Last firmware update was from November 2012, please update if you haven't already.

Comment: Just for reference, there are a couple of bugs on launchpad related to the GTX 580. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdrm/+bug/990411
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/925048
 It seems that particular card, while powerful, isn't well supported by the linux drivers.

Comment: @hbdgaf In other words: Try using the Intel graphics and unplug the Nvidia card, if in doubt. :) EDIT: The Windows partition can also be resized in Windows.

Comment: I have a 120 gig SSD (OCZ V3) running windows 8 duel booted with Ubuntu. Works fine for me. The installation was the same process as always.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I'm a linux noob, how would I get that?
 my motherboard doesn't support me using the Intel's integrated card, unfortunately. And I tried resizing the windows partition, but it failed in windows too - I ended up formatting the entire drive and trying yesterday, and that's where my "Edit" came from now. Thanks for your replies everyone!

Comment: @hbdgaf My motherboard doesn't support the integrated GPU (Intel HD 4000) from my processor, unfortunately - no video-out port. Also, aren't those bugs from 12.04? I would hope they would've been addressed by 13.04, but I guess who really knows.

Comment: It's not closed, so it still exists.  Read.

Comment: @hbdgaf I did read it, but I've never looked at their Bug system so I wasn't aware that they got closed when they were resolved. Good to know, though. I'll report back with results whenever I feel like breaking Windows yet again.

Comment: breaking windows isn't a thing.  it's broken when you open the box, so it not working doesn't count.

Comment: @hbdgaf I tried all of the workarounds listed, among others on the site, and I haven't had any luck - when I do get the driver installed, I just get a black screen and have to Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get terminal up. Any other ideas? I really appreciate your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS & 13 on Samsung SSD 830 and Verbatim 64 GB SSD without any problems. Paralell to windows XP,7, Win8 32&64 bit as Dualboot Systems.
On Notebook and Desktop Systems.

Guess your OCZ SSD is the problem ?
My expierences with a lot  of OCZ SSD's in the Windows World where not satisfying!
So i early switçhed to the Samsung 470 and 830 Series they all work fine.

Comment: This wasn't the problem, actually. Ended up having to mess with my Xorg.conf file